# CMD Command to Copy files with certain extension

Tags: cmd

So I'm using this command to copy only txt files from a certain directory to another directory

```
for /R c:\source %%f in (*.xml) do copy %%f x:\destination\
```

But it only copies over the text files without a space in the name, so it copies test.txt but not test 2.txt. How do I make it so it copies txt files with spaces?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add quotes just around the variable after the copy command:

```
for /R c:\source %%f in (*.xml) do copy "%%f" x:\destination\
```

Comment: It's probably worth explaining that you need quotes around files with spaces in them in your answer. I stared at this for a few seconds before I noticed what was different.

Comment: For me, Windows 7 cmd this worked (single percent signs): for /R c:\source %f in (*.xml) do copy "%f" x:\destination\

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with

```
copy c:\source\*.xml x:\destination\ >nul
```

---

**[Edit]** Oh I see, you want to copy all the files in all directories recursively, but without copying the directory structure.  Nevermind, then.